# Create covering index for date range (and other fields)

Tags: mongodb, indexing

This is using mongodb 2.0.4. We have thought of upgrading, but just want to see if we can fix this without doing so, as an upgrade is not easy with our setup.

I have a lot of update queries where the 'find' part looks like this:

```
timestamp:
{
    $gte: ISODate('xxxxx'),
    $lt: ISODate('xxxxx')
},
id: "string"
processed: false
```

It basically searches for records within a certain date range for a specific ID, and updates processed from false to true (it's a "worker" process).

I tried creating an index that included all 3 fields (as well as _id), but `explain()` still returns `indexOnly: false`. Oddly enough it also returns this for indexBounds:

```
"indexBounds" : {
    "processed" : [
        [
            false,
            false
        ]
    ]
}
```

Can someone give me a hint as to how to fix this so mongodb uses the index properly (a covering index) or is it simply impossible with date ranges?

Comment: What indexes have you tried creating, plus covered queries apply to the full cursor, not just the find condition, aka your return document must also only be indexed fields.

Comment: Sammaye: I am aware of the return document thing, but in this case it is an update whose only update is to set "processed: false", so it should be covered. Tried creating an index containing the 3 fields involved (timestamp, id, processed) as well as _id, but it did not show as covering.

Comment: No update will be covered, it is impossible, a covered query can only exist on a find. A $set can make an atomic operation within the document if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's important is not just having an index with all three fields, but what *order* the fields are in.

I recommend this [article](http://emptysquare.net/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/) to get more details about how compound indexes are used.

The main thing to keep in mind is that fields where you test for equality need to be before fields where you test for ranges (especially since you're on a version that's old that does not have some optimizations that were made in later versions).

Comment: I am beginning to think more and more that we are desperately missing some non-obvious, non-documented internal optimizations in the order of fields and how they are handled with regards to indexes, by simply being a few versions behind. I read a similar article to the one you linked, and it was a real eye-opener.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all optimizations you need to be aware of are documented :)